# How do I undo a change to a combo box in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to prevent users from accidentally changing a combo box selection once they've already made the selection, by having a yes/no message box appear during the On Change event of the combo box.

The Undo isn't working.  The new value is still in the field after they click No.

The idea is if they select No the previous value will be input rather than the new one.

I tried the Before Update and After Update as well, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```vb
Private Sub CboClient_Change()
If MsgBox("Do you want to change the client?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    Me!CboClient.Undo
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a global variable on this UserForm, then you set the value of the Dropdown/Combobox in this variable when you open or fill the UserForm. Now you can use this variable to compare old with new value on the `ComboBox1_Change()` Event. You then setup your Question code and if No, set the `ComboBox1.Value` to the Global variable which has the old one. If the answer is Yes, then update Global variable with the New Value so you are ready in case the ComboBox is changed again.

Answer (score 1):

Use combobox OldValue property. This works for me:

```
Private Sub cboClient_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
With Me
If Not IsNull(.cboClient.OldValue) And .cboClient.OldValue <> .cboClient Then
    If MsgBox("Do you want to change the client?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
        .cboClient.Undo
    End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.